# Filter results in angularjs based on select value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angular-filters

This seems like it should be easy but I am new to angular and not grasping this concept very well. I am hoping to run an ng-repeat over a dataset and then be able to filter the results based on a selected option in a select box, using the exact same dataset.

I have created an array of options and assigned them to the variable $scope.OurTeamCategories.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.ourTeamCategories = [
        {"id":18,"title":'Management'},
        {"id":19,"title":'Administration'},
        {"id":21,"title":'Designers'},
        {"id":22,"title":'Accounts'},
    ]
}]);
```

Then in the HTML File I am dynamically create the select box using ng-options and use ng-repeat to create a list of these the categories. This all works fine, but now I want to be able to filter

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Main">
    <select name="show-filter"  ng-model="catFilter" ng-options="category.title for category in ourTeamCategories">
          <option value="{{category.id}}"></option>
      </select>

  <li ng-repeat="cat in ourTeamCategories">
      <h3>{{cat.title}}</h3>
      <!-- for testing -->
     <b>input: {{catFilter.id}}</b> - - ID: {{cat.id}}
  </li>
   </div>
</div>
```

I thought I would be able to run a filter in the following way, but I am getting an error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<li ng-repeat="cat in ourTeamCategories | filter {cat.id:catFilter.value}">
```

I've created a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YwHknAm3X2NUdxDeUjS8?p=preview

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to mention direct id in your filer like `id` that will look up through `ourTeamCategories` id & for more accurate result do add `true` at the end will ensure the exact matching rather than contains & also missed colon `:`

```
<li ng-repeat="cat in ourTeamCategories | filter : {id: catFilter.id}: true">
```

**Update**

You are mixing up two approaches at the same time like `ng-options` with `ng-repeat`. I think you should stick with `ng-options`, so in your current ng-option which is setting `title` value in your `ng-model`

```
<select name="show-filter" ng-model="catFilter" 
   ng-options="category as category.title for category in ourTeamCategories">
</select>
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bR1p1FnnAtnlKNYQdPPt?p=preview) here

Comment: Thanks! I think both of yours and idursun's  comments are valid and the error has gone away. However, it still doesn't seem to want to filter upon selecting the relevant select option.

Comment: I'm actually getting the expected values into the select options with my current select code. The values being 18,19,21,22. When i apply your update, the select options values are now 0,1,2,3 which are not relevant to the filtering I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Starfs Thats my bad..I missed couple of things.. now its obviously fixed..take a look at plunkr & code changes..

Comment: @Starfs thats depend on how you binding value in `ng-options` now I used `filter : {id: catFilter.id}` as `catFilter` contains whole selected object..did you looked at plunkr?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80932/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-starfs).

Comment: Any one knows what is the reference webpage that talking about the trailing `true` in `filter` of `ng-repeat` in abov example ?? It seems that Angular JS has many hidden properties, methods, parameters, etc......

Comment: @Grace you can find it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), It is a comparator function property, the shorthand value for `function(actual, expected) { return angular.equals(actual, expected)}` is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You need a colon after `filter`. Try this:

`filter: {cat.id:catFilter.value}`